# Asp.net Core How to Specify TargetFramework for PackageReference?

Tags: asp.net-core

[Despot.Data.csproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrtHV.png)

```
CommonDll(.net standard 2.0)
----<PackageReference Include="Despot.Data" Version="1.0.0" />

ProjectA(netcoreapp2.2)
----<PackageReference Include="CommonDll" />
OutputFiles
----Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.6
----Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.2.6

ProjectB(netcoreapp3.1)
----<PackageReference Include="CommonDll" />
OutputFiles
----Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.1
----Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 3.0.1
```

I want netcoreapp3.1 output the same as netcoreapp2.2, can we do this? how? 
help!!!

Comment: Why dont the two projects have same `<TargetFramework>`?

Answer (score 0):

Set a specific version in `<PackageReference>` if you don't want the version base on the `<TargetFramework>`, in your `ProjectB.csproj`.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.6" />
```

Comment: It not work.  because i have some projects use sql server 2005 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3 does not supported row number pager anymore. so i want to use the netcoreapp3.1 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.6.

Comment: Well, then you should solve the Paging (row number pager) instead - update the question, with how you did this paging :)

Comment: This is just one of the problems, actually i want  my Despot.Data lib compatible netcoreapp2.2 and netcoreapp3.1 both, i want to specific version through CommonDll(.net standard 2.0). i thought it would be compiled according to CommonDll's targetframework. as you can see. it's always according to the running project, but thank you.

Comment: All projects the ends in the same solution (web/.exe), should have the same targetframework or alike .net standard.